# Construct a Lan in VMware Player

Tags: networking, vmware-player, windows-server-2012-r2

This is probably a frequently asking question, but I googled and tried for so long and still not success.
I have installed 2 guest(Windows Server 2012 R2) in my host(Win 7), and I want my guests connect each other.
I've tried set my guests in the same LAN Segment like:
[image]

but still in vain.They can't ping each other as well.

Also, I've tried other three options(Bridged,NAT,Host-only) but still won't work...

Is there any one can help me to set my guests?
I want to set their IP like:

- 192.168.0.1
- 192.168.0.2

Comment: Is your goal JUST to be able network the 2 vms, or do you require the use of LAN segments, and the 2 listed ip addresses?

Comment: Sorry, I want to set ip of the 2 vms as listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bridged your VM will see each other and your host, as if your VM were connected directly on your home / work network.

If you put them on the same virtual LAN they will only see each other.

Comment: I've tried "Bridged" but they can't ping each other.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the reason.
It turns out that the firewall of Windows Server 2012 R2 blocks "ping" defaultly.
So all I have to do is just enable it and the VMs can ping each other.
Just for those who come across the same problem.

@user2210761 was right, so I'm going to accept his/her answer though my problem is actually the firewall.